# Struggling to display a message (“Guess a number!!!”) whenever the user/player doesn’t type a number

Tags: dialog, integer, applescript, comparison, display

As I’m learning how to write codes in AppleScript, I’ve created this simple game to put my still-not-very-big knowledge into practice.

My code displays a message asking the user/player to guess a number between 1 and 20 and compares their input with the randomly chosen one. When the player's guess = randomly chosen number, the game ends. Until that, it keeps asking the player to guess lower or higher.

I’m struggling to display a message (“Guess a number!!!”) whenever the user/player doesn’t type a number, but a letter or any other symbol other than a number.

I’ve realized that if I don’t get the user/player’s input “as integer”, the compiler won’t compare it in order to check if it’s inside or outside the given range (1 to 20).

But as I do this, whenever the user/player doesn’t type a number (but a letter or any other symbol other than a number), the compiler will display an error that says it can’t transform this character into an integer.

Thus, I can’t even use an if statement to make the compiler display my message (“Guess a number!!!”) whenever the user/player doesn’t type a number!

It would be something like:
        If playersGuess ≠ integer then
        display dialog "Guess a number!!!"
        end if

How do I go about solving this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
set RandomNumber to (random number from 1 to 20) as integer

display dialog RandomNumber

set EndOfGame to false

set NoOfTries to 0

repeat until EndOfGame is true

    set Playersguess to the text returned of (display dialog "I'm thinking on a number between 1 and 20. Guess which one it is!" default answer "" buttons {"Ok"} default button 1) as integer

    if Playersguess = RandomNumber then
        set NoOfTries to NoOfTries + 1

        if NoOfTries > 1 then
            display dialog "Very well! It took you " & NoOfTries & " tries to guess the number I was thinking."
            set EndOfGame to true

        else
            display dialog "Very well! It took you " & NoOfTries & " try to guess the number I was thinking."
            set EndOfGame to true

        end if

    else if (Playersguess > RandomNumber) and (Playersguess < 21) and (Playersguess ≠ RandomNumber) then
        display dialog "Wrong guess! Guess lower!"
        set NoOfTries to NoOfTries + 1

    else if (Playersguess < RandomNumber) and (Playersguess > 0) and (Playersguess ≠ RandomNumber) then
        display dialog "Wrong guess! Guess higher!"
        set NoOfTries to NoOfTries + 1

    else if Playersguess > 20 then
        display dialog "Guess a number up to 20!!!"

    else if Playersguess < 1 then
        display dialog "Guess a number starting at 1!!!"

    end if

end repeat
```

Comment: Consider [this example](https://paste.ee/p/hVaOg). The checking of the players input is handled in the body of the `playGame` [function](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH), which invokes itself when a player either; guesses incorrectly, enters a non-number, enters nothing, or the no. is out of range. It correctly handles decimal numbers the player may input e..g. 7.3. It avoids having to specify a list of all the possible numbers within the range

Answer (score 0):

I added two properties to the beginning of your script. I also added this repeat loop `repeat while {Playersguess} is not in validNumbers` to your code which is an example of how you can address the event that somebody entered an integer larger than 20 or any other key value that I did not define in the `validNumbers` property... Wrapping this part of your code... `set Playersguess to the text returned of` inside of a `try` block allows for the code to continue on if it encounters an error.

There are several other issues with your code that will need to be addressed, but for now, the adjustments that I made should be able to put you back on the right track.

```
property validNumbers : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
property Playersguess : missing value

set RandomNumber to (random number from 1 to 20) as integer

display dialog RandomNumber

set EndOfGame to false
set NoOfTries to 0

repeat until EndOfGame is true

    repeat while {Playersguess} is not in validNumbers
        try
            set Playersguess to the text returned of (display dialog "I'm thinking on a number between 1 and 20. Guess which one it is!" default answer "" buttons {"Ok"} default button 1) as integer
        end try
        if {Playersguess} is not in validNumbers then
            display dialog "Please Only Enter Numerals From 1 to 20" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
        end if
    end repeat

    if Playersguess = RandomNumber then
        set NoOfTries to NoOfTries + 1
        if NoOfTries > 1 then
            display dialog "Very well! It took you " & NoOfTries & " tries to guess the number I was thinking."
            set EndOfGame to true
            set Playersguess to missing value
        else
            display dialog "Very well! It took you " & NoOfTries & " try to guess the number I was thinking."
            set EndOfGame to true
            set Playersguess to missing value
        end if
    else if (Playersguess > RandomNumber) and (Playersguess < 21) and (Playersguess ≠ RandomNumber) then
        display dialog "Wrong guess! Guess lower!"
        set NoOfTries to NoOfTries + 1
    else if (Playersguess < RandomNumber) and (Playersguess > 0) and (Playersguess ≠ RandomNumber) then
        display dialog "Wrong guess! Guess higher!"
        set NoOfTries to NoOfTries + 1
    else if Playersguess > 20 then
        display dialog "Guess a number up to 20!!!"
    else if Playersguess < 1 then
        display dialog "Guess a number starting at 1!!!"
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Why the braces around `"{Playersguess}"` ?

Comment: If the random number was let's say `5`, and a player enters `4.5` then this assumes they've guessed it correctly. Is that intentional?